# SASS @at-root directive not compiling

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have the following code in an .scss file:

```
*[data-toggle="popover"]{
    font-weight: bold;
    @at-root .list-group-item & { 
        margin-left: 2rem;
    }
}
```

On http://sassmeister.com it compiles as I want:

```
*[data-toggle="popover"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.list-group-item *[data-toggle="popover"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

But locally it doesn't do anything with the @at-root directive, so I get:

```
*[data-toggle="popover"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  @at-root .list-group-item & {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

}
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I've updated my sass and compass to the latest versions. What else can I do?

Comment: What's the "latest versions"?

Comment: SASS 3.3.14 (Maptastic Maple),

Compass 0.12.7 (Alnilam)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCSS Map won't compile in Compass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942885/scss-map-wont-compile-in-compass)

Comment: Yes, you're correct, the solution provided there solved my issue.

Comment: Better duplicate match:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427567/is-sass-3-3-3-compatible-with-compass

Comment: http://sass-compatibility.github.io/#at_root_directive

Its not supported in ruby sass version 3.3 - upgrade to 3.4